# Conformal map from region between branches of hyperbola to circular region

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, proof-explanation

In studying Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*, a map $T$ is constructed from $w$-plane to $z$-plane by $z=w+\dfrac1w$. And setting $w=\rho e^{i\theta}$, fixing $\rho$ gives circle which correspond to an ellipse in $z$-plane, while fixing $\theta$ gives ray which corresponds to hyperbola. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8REI.png)

The purpose of this section is to find maps from these regions onto $D^2$. So we should consider its inverse map $G$ with domain as open connected subset of $D^2$ instead (given by one of the branch $w=z-\sqrt{z^2-1}$).

However, unlike what is claimed in the book, as the boundary circle of $\overline{D^2}$ is absent, the real axis is actually missing from the image set no matter what domain is chosen for $G$. Hence the region between branches of hyperbola is not being mapped onto.

Of course, the problem can be solved by relaxing the domain of $G$ to be $D^2\bigcup\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in[0,\pi]\}$. However, I think the domain should be made open connected region.

Also, to actually construct the domain, we specify one hyperbola corresponding to ray of argument $\theta_0$ (in fact $-\theta_0$, $\pi+\theta_0$ are possible choice). Let $Q$ be the region between two branches, it correspond to two separate sector (see <s>https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFL4T.png</s>, should be https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvjrT.png). The disconnectedness may lead to difficulties in constructing further map to upper half plane.

So how to solve the above questions? Thanks for any help.

P.S. The question can be treated as the following as well: how to continue with this trick to take the corresponding circular region to $D^2$?

For if it is answered, then the above subtle question about connectedness of image set need not be concerned anymore.

P.S.2 Actually region $Q$ **(with infinity)** projected back on Riemann's sphere just looks like bracelet, which is not simply connected. So intuitively our elementary way (LFT, power map, exponential map restricted to be made injective) of analytic mapping retaining bijectivity is not applicable here since by open mapping theorem, it should be homeomorphism which contradicts the number of connected components they have.

(Plus @Maxim 's comment, $Q$ without infinity is simply connected)

So we should just take say $f(z)=z^m$ ($m$ large) as the answer?

Comment: Confocal hyperbolas and regions map to orthogonal confocal ellipses of corresponding regions.

Comment: @Narasimham But here the hyperbola are mapped to pair of diameter in $D^2$ which is a limiting form of hyperbola, doesn't seem like ellipse. Of course, they are still confocal.

Comment: Would cartesian  plotting  real, im parts of $ w= z+1/z;\;z=x+iy $ of any relevance? One gets $[ x(1+1/(x^2+y^2),y(1-1/(x^2+y^2)]$. These curves are different.

Comment: $Q$ (without $\infty$) is the exterior of a figure-eight curve on the Riemann sphere, it is simply connected. Consider where the Joukowsky transform maps the wedge $\{r e^{i t}: r > 0 \land \pi/4 < t < 3 \pi/4 \}$.

Comment: @Maxim It should be https://imgur.com/BPPI4cX , which is only half our target and $x$-axis removed. (Provided that the domain of $G$ is $D^2$ not $\overline{D^2}$.)
Of course, if by the wedge you mean $\{re^{it}:r\in(0,\infty)\&t\in(\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4)\}$ but not $\{re^{it}:r\in(0,1)\&t\in(\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4)\}$, then we can put back the segment of $x$-axis in the image above.

Comment: $r > 0$ means $r > 0$, not $0 < r < 1$. The Joukowsky transform is injective on the infinite wedge, clearly that adds more than a segment of the real axis to your image.

Comment: Oh I just mix up complex inversion ($\frac1z$) with inversion in circles ($\frac1{\bar{z}}$) which make me suspect that the map $T$ is not injective on the infinite sector, thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Maxim's comment, I understand that my confusion comes from the following point:

I tried to understand the inverse map $G$ of $z=w+\frac1w$ instead of $T$ itself which complicates the matter, limiting myself to unit disc $D^2$ or its closure as domain. However, this is resolved if I concentrate instead on $T$ as a separate map, then I can conclude easily that $T$ is injective on an infinite sector in the upper half plane. From there, we can induce the inverse map $G$ rather than inducing it in the beginning.

Hence the answer is as the following:

let $T:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ by $T(w)=w+\frac1w=z$, it is injective on the infinite sector $S$ with argument between $\theta,\pi-\theta$ where $\theta\in(0,\frac\pi2)$, its image is the region between two branches of hyperbola (with parametrisation $\dfrac{x^2}{\cos^2\theta}-\dfrac{y^2}{\sin^2\theta}=1$).

Let $T'$ be restriction on $S$ and $G$ be its inverse, which is our desired conformal map (conformal because it doesn't include point $\pm1$)

In fact, even with the original view, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvjrT.png as our desired image set, it can almost be seen as open by gluing the upper arc to the absent lower arc. We then complete our work by the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, showing what I got from my comment.

[image]

Further solving  $(u,v)$ in terms of$(x,y)$

$$ u (1 + 1/(u^2 + v^2)) = x, v (1 - 1/(u^2 + v^2)) = y $$

results in sixth order $(x,y)$ polynomials.